Populating and replicating tables based on JSON object
I'm wanting to populate these tables based on what data is in a JSON object. I don't have said JSON object yet, so I hard coded a similar one.
From james to submit is what I want to be replicated based on how many people are in this object.
The first block of code is my hard coded bits with how I want them to work (no need to worry about the  there), the second bit is an example object that will be similar to the database info I receive that I want to populate EACH table with.



$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log(personInformation);

  $('#personSearch').on('input', function() {
    let value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    let searchVal1 = $('.personRow').find('td').text();
    let searchVal2 = $('.personRow').text();
    $('form').filter(function() {

      console.log('searchVal1', searchVal1);
      console.log('searchVal2', searchVal2);
      $(this).toggle($(this).text()
        .toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > 0);
    });
  });
});
tr .hiddenRow {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Person</div>

        <div class="search-dropdown group">
          <label>Person: </label>

          <div class="dropdown-display" id="dropdownDisplay">
            <span id="personVal">Select person</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="personSearch" class="search-input">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
          <form style="display:none" action="" method="get" target="_parent" name="personInfo" id="personInfo">
            <input name="state" type="hidden" value="AL"></input>
            <input name="county" type="hidden" value="St. Clair"></input>

            <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
              <tbody>
                <tr class="personRow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1" data-search="jamesjohnsonidfromsql" class="accordion-toggle">
                  <td><input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="NAME from sql1">james</input> <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="NAME from sql">johnson</input>
                  </td>
                  <td><input type="hidden" name="person_id" value="id from sql">ID from sql</input>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Category from sql</td>
                  <td>Amount from sql</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow">
                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo1">
                      <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                          <tr class="info">
                            <th>Address:</th>
                            <th>DOB:</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                          <tr data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle">
                            <td>address</td>
                            <td>birthday</td>
                          </tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td>Fees:</td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td>fee name(s)</td>
                            <td>amount(s)</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <p class="button-group">
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </p>
          </form>

          <form style="display:none" action="" method="get" target="_parent" name="personInfo" id="personInfo">
            <input name="state" type="hidden" value="AL"></input>
            <input name="county" type="hidden" value="St. Clair"></input>

            <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
              <tbody>
                <tr class="personRow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2" data-search="jordantestidfromsql" class="accordion-toggle">
                  <td><input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="NAME from sql2">jordan</input> <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="NAME from sql">test</input>
                  </td>
                  <td><input type="hidden" name="person_id" value="id from sql">ID from sql</input>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Category from sql</td>
                  <td>Amount from sql</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow">
                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo2">
                      <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                          <tr class="info">
                            <th>Address:</th>
                            <th>DOB:</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                          <tr data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle">
                            <td>address</td>
                            <td>birthday</td>
                          </tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td>Fees:</td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td>fee name(s)</td>
                            <td>amount(s)</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <p class="button-group">
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </p>
          </form>

          <form style="display:none" action="" method="get" target="_parent" name="personInfo" id="personInfo">
            <input name="state" type="hidden" value="AL"></input>
            <input name="county" type="hidden" value="St. Clair"></input>

            <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
              <tbody>
                <tr class="personRow" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3" data-search="mattgottlichidfromsql" class="accordion-toggle">
                  <td><input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="NAME from sql3">matt</input> <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="NAME from sql">test</input>
                  </td>
                  <td><input type="hidden" name="person_id" value="id from sql">ID from sql</input>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Category from sql</td>
                  <td>Amount from sql</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow">
                    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo3">
                      <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                          <tr class="info">
                            <th>Address:</th>
                            <th>DOB:</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                          <tr data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle">
                            <td>address</td>
                            <td>birthday</td>
                          </tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td>Fees:</td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td>fee name(s)</td>
                            <td>amount(s)</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <p class="button-group">
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </p>
          </form>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test">

  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
const personInformation = [{
    "inmate_id": 1,
    "first_name": "James",
    "middle_name": "",
    "last_name": "Johnson",
    "dob": "1/1/2000",
    "address": [{
      "type": "MAILING",
      "line1": "94317 Roxbury Court",
      "line2": "Apt 102",
      "city": "Tampa",
      "state": "FL",
      "zip": 33625
    }],
    "fees": [{
        "name": "st. clair",
        "amount": "$35"
      },
      {
        "name": " fee",
        "amount": "amount calculated"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "inmate_id": 2,
    "first_name": "Jordan",
    "middle_name": "Null",
    "last_name": "",
    "dob": "1/12/86",
    "address": [{
      "type": "MAILING",
      "line1": "94317 Roxbury Court",
      "line2": "Apt 102",
      "city": "Tampa",
      "state": "FL",
      "zip": 33625
    }],
    "fees": [{
        "name": "st. clair",
        "amount": "$35"
      },
      {
        "name": "fee",
        "amount": "amount calculated"
      }
    ]
  }
];
</script>



